# Flutter: ScrollSnapList-Item not shrinking - need dynamic sizing of elements

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building a horizontal ScrollSnapList. My problem is that I cannot shrink it on the y-axis to the size of the elements height. I tried to give a maxHeight with LimitedBox but the ScrollSnapList takes alle the vertical space available. I have also tried for test purposes to build it with a ListView.builder() - same result:

Hers is my Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const AppBarProfile(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          LimitedBox(
            maxHeight: 140,
            child:

            ScrollSnapList(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              key: sslKey,
              initialIndex: 0,
              //shrinkWrap: true,,
              //duration: 1,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              onItemFocus: (index){
                _currentIndex = index;
              },
              itemSize: MediaQuery. of(context). size. width - 32,
              itemBuilder: _buildItem,
              itemCount: 10,
              scrollPhysics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              dynamicItemSize: true,
              dynamicItemOpacity: 0.7,
              dynamicSizeEquation: (distance) {
                if (distance > 0){
                  return 1 - 0.1*distance /MediaQuery. of(context). size. width / 2;
                }else{
                  return 1 + 0.1*distance /MediaQuery. of(context). size. width / 2 ;
                }

                },
                  ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(height: 200, color: Colors.black,),
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return
         SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery. of(context). size. width - 32,
          child: Item(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code of the element being called:

```
class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      onTap: () {
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Container(height:10, width: 20, color: Colors.black)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Result of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8uDd.png)

As you can see, the space around the items of ScrollSnapList is expanded to the size of the maxHeight of LimitedBox(). I placed another black container beneath to show that it is fully expanding. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you include more about `_buildItem`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Sorry, forgot to change the name from my original Code - updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick wrapping with Center widget.

```dart
Widget _buildEmployeeItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32,
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 10,
        width: 20,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: As for the horizontalList with dynamic height, you can try SingleChildScrollView with Row widget.

Comment: SingleChildScrollView is not an option because I need the snap function.

Comment: Your answer fixed the size of the container, but not the expansion of the space around it. I've updated my question. Can you still help?

Comment: Sorry don't know about this. you can create custom animation like snap, also you can check different package